# How to annotate a bar plot with a bracket

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, plot-annotations

I want to place a bracket over a fraction of my data in a histogram to appear similar to the figure below. Can anyone show me how to do this with my code?

[Age demographic sizes in the UK population](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHH8T.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#reads CSV raw file on github
df = pd.read_csv ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryan-j-hope/Shielding-models/master/2020%20Uk%20Population%20By%20Age%20Demographics.csv", encoding='UTF')

#removes row 10
df.drop(10,inplace = True)

print(df)

#plots and lables chart
ag = df["Age Group"]

pop = df["Population (%)"]

plt.ylabel("Population (%)")

plt.xlabel("Age Group")

plt.bar(ag, pop)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max(pop[-4:])` calculates the vertical position to start the bracket as the maximum of the bars involved. With adequate `x` and `y` coordinates the full bracket can be drawn.

The average of the bar positions can be used as x-coordinate for the text.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ag = ['0', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90']
pop = [12, 11, 13, 14, 13, 14, 11, 9, 4, 1]
plt.ylabel("Population (%)")
plt.xlabel("Age Group")
plt.bar(ag, pop)

index1 = 6
index2 = 9
h = max(pop[index1:index2+1]) # maximum of the involved bar heights
bx = [index1-0.5, index1-0.5, index2+0.5, index2+0.5]
by = [h + 0.5, h + 1, h + 1, h + 0.5]
plt.plot(bx, by, 'k-', lw=2)
plt.text((index1 + index2) / 2, h + 1.5, f'{sum(pop[index1:index2+1]):.0f} %', size=20, ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I don't understand why you had to re-draw the chart. I also don't understand why when I take the bottom portion of the code, describing the annotation and place it into my original code it ruins the chart output.

Comment: What do you mean by "redraw"? I just took the values to create an independent example (that keeps worknig when the github input would be removed). `plt.plot` only adds the 3 line segments to draw the bracket.  If you post your updated code (editing the question), people can look and see where the undesired behavior comes from.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I just tested with your code and copy pasting my answer below, but where `ag` and `pop` are defined exactly as in the question. The generated output looks the same to me. But you need to remove the **plt.show** in the middle of the code. It can only be at the end.  `plt.show` erases the plot directly after showing it.